# Spring-security 6 - 403 denied because AuthenticationProvider not called

Tags: spring, spring-security

I've recently upgraded a project from using spring-security `6.0.0-M6` to `6.0.0`, [gradle config](https://github.com/au-research/raido-v2/blob/f0b5de3e1c60fcf9450030564263f1bb0c682080/settings.gradle#L19) if you want to see it.
This project does not use spring-boot.

## Context

My `securityFilterChain` is configured via code and looks approximately like this:

```java
http.
  authenticationManager(authnManager).
  securityContext().securityContextRepository(securityRepo).
and().
  authorizeRequests(). // <-- DEPRECATED
    requestMatchers(RAID_V2_API + "/**").fullyAuthenticated().
```

The [full codebase, starting with the FilterChain config](https://github.com/au-research/raido-v2/blob/f0b5de3e1c60fcf9450030564263f1bb0c682080/api-svc/spring/src/main/java/raido/apisvc/spring/config/RaidWebSecurityConfig.java#L53), is publicly available.

Note that usage of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`  is [deprecated](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter), and I have not been using it since the original usage of `6.0.0-M6`.  So calling stuff like `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.authenticationManagerBean()` won't work.

This code works fine, but the call to `authorizeRequests()` causes a deprecation warning that I want to get rid of.

## Problem

The deprecation tag says that I should use `authorizeHttpRequests()` instead, but when I do that - requests that require authorization (via the `fullyAuthenticated()` specification above) will be denied with a 403 error.

## Analysis

It seems this happens because my `AuthenticationProvider` instances aren't being called,
because the `ProviderManager` isn't being called.  Since the AuthnProviders don't get called, the security context still contains the pre-auth token instead of a verified post-auth token, so the eventual call to `AuthorizationStrategy.isGranted()` ends up calling `isAuthenticated()` on the pre-auth token, which (correctly) returns false and the request is denied.

## Question

How do I use the `authorizeHttpRequests()` method but still have the `ProviderManager` be called so that my security config works?

My workaround is just to ignore the deprecation warning.

Comment: I'd like to understand who should call your `AuthenticationManager`. Since you disabled `httpBasic` and I see no other filter capable of performing authentication it is expected that your `AuthenticationManager` won't be called. If I'm mistaken, add more information to your question like a sample request, the filters etc.

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio There are no other filters that I recall.  The links in the question are to the full codebase. The `RaidWebSecurityConfig` linked to by "java config" is the full spring-security config. The sibling `ApiConfig` file is the full spring config. Sub-directories contain other spring config, but none of that is relevant to spring-security.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, your security configuration does not specify any kind of authentication, like `httpBasic`, `formLogin`, etc. The `AuthenticationManager` is invoked by the filters created by those authentication mechanisms in order to authenticate credentials.

Second, the application is probably unwittingly relying on `FilterSecurityInterceptor` (`authorizeRequests`) to authenticate the user, which is not supported with `authorizeHttpRequests`. You need to declare an auth mechanism that collects credentials from the request and authenticates the user.

Because you are using JWT, you might want to consider Spring Security's [OAuth2 Resource Server support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/index.html). You can also refer to our [samples repository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples) in order to help you with sample configurations.

Comment: Thank you Marcus! Your answer helped me a lot. After long hours of debugging and switching back and forth between sp-sec-5 and sp-sec-6 and comparing their behavior, it would be impossible to tell why it stopped invoking my custom AuthProvider after upgrade. We have auth logic split in 2 phases: in filter we extract token and verify secret added by api gateway, and full auth happens later in AuthProvider. No surprise that this design doesn't work with sp-sc-6 after your explanation.

Comment: I am also having the same kind of issue in Spring Security 6.0.2 + Spring Boot 3.0.0.  The reference for the post . 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75886117/spring-boot-and-spring-security-version-upgrade-issue-of-not-calling-custom-au

Can you please help me here?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a rough outline of what I did to to implement the "just use the resource server" suggestion from the answer.

1. include the `oauth2-resource-server` libraries in the build.
2. create an `AuthenticationManagerResolver` that replaces what the `SecuritycontextRepository` and the `FilterSecurityInterceptor` used to do:

```java
@Bean
public AuthenticationManagerResolver<HttpServletRequest>
tokenAuthenticationManagerResolver(
  AuthenticationProvider authProvider
) {
  return (request)-> {
    return authProvider::authenticate;
  };
}
```

3. change AuthenticationProvider implementations to use the `BearerTokenAuthenticationToken` class as the pre-auth token, it still works basically the same way it used to: verifying the pre-auth token and returning a post-auth token.
4. hook up the new resolver class in the `securityFilterChain` config by replacing the old `securityContextRepository()` config with the new `authenticationManagerResolver()` config, which passes in the resolver created in step 2:

```java
http.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 ->
  oauth2.authenticationManagerResolver(tokenAuthenticationManagerResolver) );
```

I like this new approach because it makes it more obvious *how* the security chain works.
It's nice to replace the custom pre-auth token implementation with the built-in class too.

Note that it's likely this config can be simplified, but I needed the custom resolver since the project uses different types of bearer token depending on the endpoint called.  Pretty sure the auth providers don't need to be `AuthenticationProvider` any more; the lambda function returned from the resolver serves that purpose - they can probably just be random spring components and as long as the method is SAM-type compatible.

The spring-security [multi-tenancy doco](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/multitenancy.html) was helpful for this.