# Spring Boot and Spring Security version upgrade - issue of not calling Custom Authorization provider

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am trying to upgrade the Spring Boot version from 2.6.9 to 3.0.5 and Spring Security is also to be upgraded from 5.7.5 to 6.0.2.

I am using custom AuthenticationProvider and this is not called after Spring boot & Spring Security upgrade.

Try:

SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) method changes,

1. Registered the custom Authentication provider in AuthenticationManager.

   ```
    List<AuthenticationProvider> authenticationProviders = new ArrayList<AuthenticationProvider>(1);
    authenticationProviders.add(customAuthenticationProvider());
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = authenticationManager(authenticationProviders);


             http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .logout().permitAll();
   ```

This is not calling the custom AuthenticationProvider.

2. Added Authentication provider also and not giving the expected result

   ```
         http.csrf()
        .disable()
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
        .authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider())
        .logout().permitAll();
   ```
3. Added the AuthenticationResolver also not calling the Custom Authentication provider.

   ```
         http
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
        .oauth2ResourceServer()
         .authenticationManagerResolver(resolver(http))
        .and()
        .authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider())
        .logout().permitAll();




    public AuthenticationManager authManager(HttpSecurity http) throws 
      Exception {
    AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder =
        http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
    authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider());
    return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
    }



    AuthenticationManagerResolver<HttpServletRequest> resolver(HttpSecurity http) {
        return request -> {
            try {
                return authManager(http);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        };
    }
   ```

I stuck in this and not getting much clues to figure out the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you find any work around for this issue? 
I have a task to upgrade the spring boot to 3 and java to 17 and now it is a week that stuck with this issue. I don't know why the overriden authentication or attemprtAuthentication why not being called

Answer (score 0):

I wasted one day to debug the issue and finally discovered the solution for my issue. There are two changes .

1. Though @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true) is deprecated in Spring Boot 3.0.0 , this annotation should be used. So that , the secureEnabled is true and calling the custom AuthenticationProvider. I came across that @EnableMethodSecurity should be used in Spring Boot 3.0.0 instead of @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity. But using @EnableMethodSecurity , not calling custom AuthenticationProvider as expected.
2. There is a change in protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) method -

   ```
       @Bean
       protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

       http
           .cors()
           .disable()
           .csrf()
           .disable()
           .authorizeHttpRequests()
           .requestMatchers("/domain/version/**").permitAll()
           .anyRequest()
           .authenticated()
           .and()
           .sessionManagement()
           .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
           .and()
           .addFilterBefore(customFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
           .logout().permitAll();

       return http.build();

   }
   ```

Note : custom AuthenticationProvider is registered as bean.

```
    @Bean
    public CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationProvider ();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Spring Boot 3.x version, you can use it as follows.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    private JwtAuthenticationManagerResolver authenticationManagerResolver;

    public SecurityConfig(JwtAuthenticationManagerResolver authenticationManagerResolver) {
        this.authenticationManagerResolver = authenticationManagerResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        ...
        http.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2ResourceServer -> oauth2ResourceServer.authenticationManagerResolver(authenticationManagerResolver));
        ...   
    }
}
```

You just should define a class(or you can define bean) like this.

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManagerResolver;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoders;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Collections;

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationManagerResolver implements AuthenticationManagerResolver<HttpServletRequest> {
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager resolve(HttpServletRequest request) {
        JwtAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new JwtAuthenticationProvider(JwtDecoders.fromIssuerLocation("your_issuer"));
        AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = new ProviderManager(Collections.singletonList(authenticationProvider));
        return authenticationManager;
    }
}
```